# PostgreSql: either a correct password or a BLANK password can access the database server

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have a VPS running a postgresql database server. Now i found either i enter a correct password or i leave the password blank, i can access the database from any remote computer. A wrong password cant get access to database.

The blank-password accessing is obviously not acceptable.

Tried from pgAdmin and a local rails application.

BTW, It's an Amazon EC2. if this would help.

Here is my `pg_hba.conf` settings:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all     postgres        md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all     postgres        127.0.0.1/32    md5
#########################
host    all     postgres        0.0.0.0/0       md5
# IPv6 local connections: 
host    all     postgres             ::1/128                 md5
```

Any idea whats happening here? Thanks a lot!!

**UPDATE**

```
$ /usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql 
Password: 
psql (9.2.4)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# show config_file;
          config_file              
---------------------------------------
/usr/local/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf
(1 row)

postgres=# show hba_file;
         hba_file              
-----------------------------------
/usr/local/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf
(1 row)
```

Seems all correct.

Comment: did you restart the database after changing your configuration?

Comment: @devanand yea, i restarted the server every time i made changes to the config file.

Comment: run `SHOW config_file;` to find out if you have changed the right files

Comment: @devanand seems all correct according to the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, ****! Finally, i found the awnser to this problem. 
So the reason I don't need a password to access my database server is that, `.pgpass` file have stored my password on my local computer. So that i don't have to enter password for connecting to the remote server.

I never knew `.pgpass` file would work this way. So, if someone is new to postgresql like me. Hope this could be help.

Thanks for all the other answers!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have edited the right config file (ie. the one used by postgres server)? Note that there are some example configuration files that come with postgres distribution. Also - have you restarted the server after making the changes to your configuration?

Another question - how do you access your database? Is it from an application or from command line (ie. psql command)?

If it is from command line, then don't worry about that, since it will only give you access if you are logged to shell as postgres user, and to login as postgres user you will have to be root first.

Comment: I tried pgAdmin and a rails application connecting to the database on that server. Both the same.

Comment: I think im sure, ive edit the right config file. I even changed the local access to `md5`. Now local access is prompted for password. But, the remote access can use a blank password. Im so confused.

Comment: That's strange - try to change `md5` to `reject` in the line containing `0.0.0.0/0`. Then you shouldn't be able to login remotely at all. If it is not the case then it is certainly not the file used by your server.

Comment: I just tried with `reject` as you said. Its now rejecting connection for postgres user to the database. Seems the config file is the right one. I then changed reject to md5 again. And the BLANK password got access again.....

Comment: I can see two explanations for this behavior. First - the `md5` hash of your password is exactly the same as the hash of a blank string - then I am really keen to know what it is? :) Alternatively, the configuration you pasted is not complete, and there is a line like `host  all  postgres  0.0.0.0/0  trust` somewhere (maybe someone added it intentionally as a backdoor for your database?).

Comment: haha the first explanation is unlikely to happen right? For the second situation, ive just created a blank pg_hba.conf file and paseted a clean settings into that. But seems its the issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

these are my setting. you are missing the others maybe

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

local   all             all                                     md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                md5
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```